# Как изменить checkout fields в личном кабинете WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно кастомизировать поля адреса доставки в личном кабинете WooCommerce?В интернете огромное количество материалов на тему кастомизации checkout fields на странице оформления заказа, но найти какую-либо информацию по редактировании формы в аккаунте пользователя у меня не получилось. Нашел несколько плагинов с такой функцией, но в бесплатной версии она недоступна.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что же вы там хотите получить или добавить?

Comment: Суть ведь не в том, что я хочу добавить, это не имет отношения к вопросу. Вопрос был в том как редактировать эту форму.

Comment: Фильтры вам в помощь, принцип тот же что и в чекауте